# Digitizing a raster against OSM , issue with ballpark transform or technique?

Tags: openstreetmap

I've pulled up a 'plot of land' raster and I'm attempting to georeference it to Openstreetmap. I can get the raster and the OSM to line up however it isn't accurate enough - there are straight lines that have warped.

I'm assuming this is an issue relating to the message, "Used a ballpark transform epsg:27700 to EPSG:3857" that I get when I add OSM as a layer to a new project set to EPSG27700.

As you may easily tell, I'm quite a novice at QGIS!

Comment: Hi Muttley, This looks like one of those problems that depend on specifics. I wonder if it might be helpful to describe the raster source and list some sample data. (Anonymized if preferable.) Also, maybe show a picture of the warped lines. In addition I would update the headline to be more specific, e.g. "Warped lines when mapping raster to OpenStreetMap." This makes it easier for people to answer.

Comment: This does not seem to be a coding questions, and therefore not appropriate for this site. You could try at gis.stackexchange.com instead.